# Spinning wheels!

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**The answer to this puzzle is a 7-letter word.**

---

```
                               I flipped a Swedish and I got lucky (----•----)                                

                                        hawa(i)(i)an ()slands 

                                 singing in Mongolia is common (•-----)              

                                 arteries veins and capillaries are part of the same system (--•--------)

             lots of systems in galaxies (--•---). cartoon is the best channel ever (-"•"-----)

                                    you can read it in the bible (------"•"-) 

                                             25 = 5  (•---)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 7-letter answer here is:

> **[CHAKRAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra)** - a word derived from the Sanskrit for 'wheels' (hence the title), referring to the focal points used in several meditation practices (with its roots in Hinduism and Buddhism).

This can be inferred by realising that each of the seven lines...

> ...obliquely clues the location of one of the [seven chakras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra#The_seven_chakra_system).

*I flipped a Swedish and I got lucky (----•----)*

> **CROWN** - here we think about flipping coins, and the Swedish currency is called the [krona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_krona) or 'Swedish **crown**'.

*hawa(i)(i)an ()slands*

> **THIRD EYE** - all instances of the letter 'i' in this phrase are indicated, with the third left blank. "Third i" is a homophone for "Third eye".

*singing in Mongolia is common (•-----)*

> **THROAT** - the practice of [**throat** singing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throat_singing) is popular in Mongolian regions.

*arteries veins and capillaries are part of the same system (--•--------)*

> **HEART** - the organ of the body is also in the circulatory system, along with the types of blood vessels listed here.

*lots of systems in galaxies (--•---). cartoon is the best channel ever (-"•"-----)*

> **SOLAR PLEXUS** - there are many **solar** systems in galaxies, and the word 'network' is missing in the second phrase (as in '[Cartoon Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartoon_Network)') - '**plexus**' is a synonym of 'network'.

*you can read it in the bible (------"•"-)*

> **SACRAL** - a word also meaning 'holy' or 'sacred', as the Bible's contents would also be considered by Christians.

*25 = 5  (•---)*

> **ROOT** - the square **root** of 25 is 5.

What about the dots and dashes that follows most of the clues? I initially missed their significance, but the OP points out in comments that...

> ...the dashes represent the words of the clue itself, with the dot suggesting that at that point there is an answer word that can actually be *inserted* into the line to aid its meaning (if presented in speech marks it is a synonym):
>
>  I flipped a Swedish **CROWN** and I got lucky (----•----)
>
>  **THROAT** singing in Mongolia is common (•-----)
>
>  arteries veins **HEART** and capillaries are part of the same system (--•--------)
>
>  lots of **SOLAR** systems in galaxies (--•---). cartoon "NETWORK" (**PLEXUS**) is the best channel ever (-"•"-----)
>
>  you can read it in the "HOLY" (**SACRAL**) bible (------"•"-)
>
>  **ROOT** 25 = 5  (•---)
>
>  *(There is no symbol set for the 'THIRD EYE' clue, because that one works slightly differently...)*

Comment: You got the right answer!  rot13(gur qbgf naq qnfurf pbeerfcbaqf gb gur ahzore bs jbeqf. Gur qbg gryyf lbh juvpu cbfvgvba gb cynpr n jbeq/flzoby).  You managed to figure out the words anyways, so nice job!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ah, I see! Yeah, I missed that (though noticed in each case that the word of interest could generally be inserted somehow). I'll edit my answer to incorporate that feature.